# How to tell version of Magento payment bridge and how to update

Tags: php, magento

we are trying to figure out what version of the Magento payment bridge we are running.  In this case, the Payment Bride is not an extension, it is the Magento Payment Bridge application that you can use if you are using Magneto Enterprise (which we are).  We need to try to figure out what version we are currently running and whether:

- an upgrade to the payment bridge is a requirement before upgrading to the latest version of Magento
- an upgrade to the payment bridge is as simple as just creating a new folder on the server currently running the payment bridge, and then dropping the new files in the new folder (doubtful, but we don't know for sure either way)

I have grepped through the files in the current payment bridge looking for version information, and I have been/am currently reading the installation documentation, but there is no mention of doing an upgrade, only how to patch an existing install with a specific patch file.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By "payment bridge" you some extension?

See: "System" -> "Magento Connect" -> "Magento Connect Manager" to get a list of installed extensions and their versions.

Comment: no, not an extension.  We are running Magento Enterprise, and are using the Magento Payment Bridge.  This isn't an extension, it's something else.

Comment: I've never worked with the enterprise edition. But in Magento nearly every basic feature is an (core-) extension. Search for: `/app/code/core/Mage/EXTENSION_NAME/etc/config.xml`

Comment: this one isn't a basic feature - it's not located there anyway.  Payment bridge is it'a own site, you have to install it separate from the base Magento install.  In that regard, I kind of assumed that you would be able to see the version like you can in the Magento admin backend, but there is no backend for the bridge, so no dice there.